# In DAML, what to return when a choice could lead to different new contracts to be created

Tags: daml

In DAML, if I have a choice called submit and it could lead to new contract approvedRequest or rejectedRequest. How should I manage the return value in the choice?

```
template Request
  with 
    content : Text
    anyone : Party
  where 
    signatory anyone

--what to return ? ApprovedRequest or RejectedRequest
    controller anyone can 
      Submit : ContractId ApprovedRequest
        do
          -- passed all the checks and approved
          create ApprovedRequest with request = Request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `Maybe (ContractId ApprovedRequest)` will work here? Alternatively, perhaps `Either (ContractId RejectedRequest, ContractId ApprovedRequest)`?

Comment: It looks like a good answer, I believe you can edit it to be more assertive, maybe explaining the idea behind it. ;)